# Draw the Olympic Games logo

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

## Challenge

Draw the Olympic Games logo...

[image: Olympic Games logo]

...as character (e.g. ASCII) art!

## Sample Output

```
      * * *               * * *               * * *
  *           *       *           *       *           *
*               *   *               *   *               *
*               * * *               * * *               *
*           *   *   *   *       *   *   *   *           *
  *       *   *       *   *   *   *       *   *       *
      * * *               * * *               * * *
          *               *   *               *
            *           *       *           *
                * * *               * * *
```

Your art doesn't have to look exactly like mine, but it has to represent the Olympic rings well enough that it's recognizable.

## Rules

- The program must write the art to the console.
- Shortest code (in bytes, any language) wins.
- **A solution that prints rings in their respective colors (or a close representation) will be awarded a minus-twenty-point bonus.**

The winner will be chosen on February 23<sup>rd</sup> at the end of the 2014 Winter Olympics.

---

## Winners

- **Gold**: marinus - [APL, 62 points](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/19053/1654)
- **Silver**: Ayiko - [Perl 6, 75 points](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/19005/1654)
- **Bronze**: evuez - [Python, 107 points](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/19003/1654)
- **Popular choice**: Danko Durbić - [Commodore 64 BASIC](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/19009/1654)

Comment: 20 bonus points. Um, why would I want +20 to my score?

Comment: @Quincunx I assume -20  was meant

Comment: Hum, this is a trademark…

Comment: @moala I think this falls under fair use policy.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs ok, if you think that the IOC is ok to comply with solely the US copyright law, no problem for me.

Comment: Be aware : http://registration.olympic.org/en/faq/detail/id/25 IOC are ùùùùù. Do not mess with them, they are really strict on the use of there logo

Comment: AFAIK, countries willing to participate in the Olympic Games have to adjust their copyright law to the IOC ideas, not the other way round.

Comment: Add a rule to include the (tm) mark also.

Comment: I've changed the wording of the bonus rule to reflect that the "twenty-point bonus" is indeed **not** 20 points *added* to your score.

Comment: To the trademark issue, I believe that this falls under nominative use, but the final decision resides with the purview of the administration and the lawyers.

Comment: In color, it's evident that they are *interlocking* rings, not merely *overlapping*. Few of the entries so far have accounted for that.

Comment: Totally IANAL: ok to write the sofware which draws the O******ic R**gs, not ok to execute it.  :-)

Comment: Surely as no money is being made, this is not illegal.

Comment: Too bad it's ASCII. Would look great with Python+Turtle for example. ;_;

Comment: How big a bonus is there for making the rings overlap in the correct way?  Maybe 50?  The only one I spotted doing this right was http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/19218/14680.

Comment: er, **s/is there/should there be/**

Comment: @SamB The challenge has already been up for a week, I'd rather keep the rules as they are in terms of bonuses.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as too broad because of the rule "Your art doesn't have to look exactly like mine, but it has to represent the Olympic rings well enough that it's recognizable."

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### APL (82) (-20 = 62)

Edit: for a change, this program is simple enough that [TryAPL](http://tryapl.com) will touch it, so you can run it there (just paste the line in).

Not sure if I can claim the 'color' bit, I'm representing them all differently though.

```
2/' ▓█░▓▒'[1+(13↑⍉n)⌈¯13↑⍉32↑¯26↑⌈1.1×11↓n←⍉c,0,2×c,0,2×c←(⍳2/10)∊⌈5+5×1 2∘○¨⍳1e4]
```

The APL console doesn't support color, so I used shaded block characters (assigning any kind of other ASCII art would be as simple as replacing the characters at the beginning of the string.)

They should look like unbroken circles (depending on your font.)

```
      2/' ▓█░▓▒'[1+(13↑⍉n)⌈¯13↑⍉32↑¯26↑⌈1.1×11↓n←⍉c,0,2×c,0,2×c←(⍳2/10)∊⌈5+5×1 2∘○¨⍳1e4]
    ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓          ████████████          ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓    
  ▓▓            ▓▓      ██            ██      ▓▓            ▓▓  
▓▓                ▓▓  ██                ██  ▓▓                ▓▓
▓▓            ░░░░░░░░░░░░          ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒              ▓▓
▓▓          ░░    ▓▓  ██  ░░      ▒▒    ██  ▓▓  ▒▒            ▓▓
▓▓        ░░      ▓▓  ██    ░░  ▒▒      ██  ▓▓    ▒▒          ▓▓
▓▓        ░░      ▓▓  ██    ░░  ▒▒      ██  ▓▓    ▒▒          ▓▓
▓▓        ░░      ▓▓  ██    ░░  ▒▒      ██  ▓▓    ▒▒          ▓▓
  ▓▓      ░░    ▓▓      ██  ░░  ▒▒    ██      ▓▓  ▒▒        ▓▓  
    ▓▓▓▓▓▓░░▓▓▓▓          ██░░██▒▒████          ▓▓▒▒▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓    
          ░░                ░░  ▒▒                ▒▒            
            ░░            ░░      ▒▒            ▒▒              
              ░░░░░░░░░░░░          ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
```

Or:

```
      2/' bByRg'[1+(13↑⍉n)⌈¯13↑⍉32↑¯26↑⌈1.1×11↓n←⍉c,0,2×c,0,2×c←(⍳2/10)∊⌈5+5×1 2∘○¨⍳1e4]
    bbbbbbbbbbbb          BBBBBBBBBBBB          RRRRRRRRRRRR    
  bb            bb      BB            BB      RR            RR  
bb                bb  BB                BB  RR                RR
bb            yyyyyyyyyyyy          gggggggggggg              RR
bb          yy    bb  BB  yy      gg    BB  RR  gg            RR
bb        yy      bb  BB    yy  gg      BB  RR    gg          RR
bb        yy      bb  BB    yy  gg      BB  RR    gg          RR
bb        yy      bb  BB    yy  gg      BB  RR    gg          RR
  bb      yy    bb      BB  yy  gg    BB      RR  gg        RR  
    bbbbbbyybbbb          BByyBBggBBBB          RRggRRRRRRRR    
          yy                yy  gg                gg            
            yy            yy      gg            gg              
              yyyyyyyyyyyy          gggggggggggg
```

Answer (score 164):

### Commodore 64 BASIC

Writing directly in the screen and color memory.

[image: Program]

**Output:**

[image: Output]

---

[Here's how you do this with sprites.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/19050/olympic-games-logo-free-style-edition/19159#19159)

Comment: That's fantastic. +1. Can we get a byte count?

Comment: Yay!  Don't forget to add an SYS 64738.

Comment: Remember that you can abbreviate commands and line numbers too on C64 BASIC if you want to golf.

Comment: This took me straight back to playing [Epyx Summer Games](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summer_Games).  Good times.

Comment: The only thing that bothers me about this answer is: How is this ascii art?

Comment: this is PETSCII-art

Comment: @Quincunx: Since [PETSCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PETSCII) is also known as CBM ASCII, this might qualify. If you want a different character to be used for drawing (to make it look more like classic ASCII art), replacing 160 (inverted space) with 42 (asterisk) in line 100 should do the trick.

Comment: If you just make the bottom two rings start from the top at the same time as the others start from the bottom, it will draw them so they are actually interlocking.

Answer (score 86):

### [HTML Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/briguy37/hT9vP/) - <strike>48</strike>, <strike>35</strike>, 33 characters (Thanks @Dom and @cnst!)

```
OOO<p style="margin:-15px 6px">OO
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: You can save more chars using:
`OOO<div style="margin:-10px 5px">OO` instead... (I think it needs to be a block though, hence the `<div/>`)

Comment: As this is not console output, you are better of at the free-style olympics contest: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/19050/15168

Comment: @DomHastings:  Good call!  Answer updated :)

Comment: Then why bother with `div`, can just use `p` instead!

Comment: @cnst Very nice!

Comment: Does this count as ASCII art?

Comment: @PygameNerd: It depends on your definition of "ASCII art":  Yes if your definition is "ASCII characters arranged to form a picture"; no if your definition is "ASCII characters in a fixed-width text editor to form a picture".  As for whether it is output to the console as CousinCocaine said, if the definition is ["The control or monitoring unit of a computer, containing the keyboard or keys, switches, etc."](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/console), then the web browser output is part of the monitor and thus the console (though this is probably not what the OP intended).

Comment: It's good for a laugh, anyway ;-)

Answer (score 76):

### BASH in color - 271 - 20 = 251 – With entangled rings ;P

```
o='_4mGA  _0mGA  _1mG\n _4m/A \A _0m/A \\_1mA /A \\\n_4mD_3m---_0mD_2m---_1mD\n _4m\A_3m/_4m/A_0m\\_3m\\A_2m/_0m/A_1m\\_2m\A _1m/\n_4mG_3mD_0m---_2mD_1m---\n_3m   A\A /A _2m\A /_1m\n _3mA G  A_2mG\n';o=${o//D/|A   |};o=${o//A/    };o=${o//G/   ---};printf "${o//_/\\e[3}"
```

Result:

[image]

---

#### And the *for fun* of it one: 61 - 20 = 41.

```
x='_4mO_3m^_0m0_2m^_1mO\n_3m V _2mV\n';printf "${x//_/\\e[3}"
```

[image]

---

LZ77 version:

```
echo H4sIALOY5VIAA12QwRXAIAhD767ghQV8CnYbXYENOnw1YqX1xk8wQGz1UiJKKRFebLX8ARsIs7g0g/djN7CdRAYC7Pf6h+5RVR3foMdTMcqHWlS3jKr5RKO/g25doJdXZ+ii75CseU2zNkGzH6HYCPKhPGmA2Wh3+7mEDHMgb/2cUPYJH2gPhtZxAQAA|base64 -d|zcat
```

Comment: Not many answers so far get the alternating overlap of the rings right, so this is worth an upvote even if the score is a bit higher.

Comment: `bash: !/\\e[3}": event not found` :(

Comment: I think your bash version is valid -- nowhere in the OP does it specify the size of the graphic -- but you need to fix the "V" shape rings.  Maybe a tilde (~) for the bottom of the rings?

Comment: @AlterLagos: You might find update works?

Comment: @AmeliaBR: Yes, That one was more for the fun of it, and not that seriously meant. Tried with various. Perhaps this is more to the liking? `x='54mO53m_50m052m_51mO\n53m U 52mU\n';printf "${x//5/\\e[3}"` – (I'm a bit evil with the 5 here.) Or even this might be better, with overlap in mind: `x='54mO53mA50m052mA51mO\n53m U 52mU\n';printf "${x//5/\\e[3}"` – though it might look more messy then the others.

Comment: Yep, with `_` worked, cool!

Comment: I try to compress it but it didn't work :( `printf "\`echo H4sIAEc+41IAA0VQyxXAIAhbhQV8qLhNufaoEzh8EYI9GUM+ir6PjEmlFFKD9YfNoS6/jMmkUBhSCByuEGzaB8g8LheC6ck0ZzIw4mTyzXdTZIudFGa+rR4R8w57szH6CS2SvTV7ezLNmRUq+w9TZjHCFx51t9CxhQ9LqFlHKAEAAA==|base64 -d|zcat\`"`

Comment: @AlvinWong: Not sure how you made the input for gzip, but updated A with a couple of lines.

Comment: Looks more like a [benzene](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benzene) than olympic circle :-)

Answer (score 76):

## Sinclair BASIC on the ZX Spectrum 48K (261 bytes)

BASIC listing:

[image: BASIC listing]

Final result:

[image: Result]

Program running and code measuring:

[image: Program running]

BASIC listing in text format:

```
5 INK VAL "7": CLS 
10 LET a=VAL "42": LET b=VAL "131": LET c=VAL "40": CIRCLE INK SGN PI;a,b,c: CIRCLE INK PI-PI;a+a+a,b,c: CIRCLE INK VAL "2";VAL "210",b,c
20 LET a=VAL "84": LET b=VAL "87": CIRCLE INK VAL "6";a,b,c: CIRCLE INK VAL "4";a+a,b,c
30 FOR l=PI-PI TO VAL "21": FOR c=PI-PI TO VAL "31": IF ATTR (l,c)<>VAL "63" THEN PRINT INK VAL "8";AT l,c;"*"
40 NEXT c: NEXT l
```

TAP file with the program, suitable for emulators or real machine using DivIDE or DivMMC:
http://www.zxprojects.com/images/stories/draw_the_olympics_flag.tap

Comment: I like the asciification part :)

Comment: This is lovely!

Comment: The use of Z80 sprite graphic is simply genial!! PS subtract 20 points for colors.

Comment: It feels so dirty to generate regular art and then make ASCII art from it. :)

Comment: Could you include the source code in a copy-able form?

Comment: Done! You can use the text version, or feed the TAP file to an emulator or real machine. Your choice :)

Answer (score 44):

So I didn't actually read properly, it's ASCII-art, so I guess this is invalid. Oops!

---

### HTML 121 (141 - 20)

```html
<pre style=line-height:3px;letter-spacing:-3px><font color=#06f>O <font color=#000>O <font color=red>O
 <font color=#fa0>O <font color=#193>O
```

In Chrome:

[image: What is this! An Olympic flag for ants?]

### PHP 103 (123 - 20)

```php
<pre style=line-height:3px;letter-spacing:-3px><?=($f='<font color=')."#06f>O ${f}#000>O ${f}red>O
 ${f}#fa0>O ${f}#193>O";
```

Comment: You can get the colours a bit closer with no penalty: blue:`#06f`, yellow:`#fa0`, green:`#193`

Comment: As this is not console output, you are better of at the free-style olympics contest: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/19050/15168

Answer (score 38):

## Ruby: 198 characters - 20 = 178

```ruby
a=[*0..9].map{[' ']*35}
d=->c,x,y=0{11.times{|i|7.times{|j|a[y+j][x+i]="^[[3#{c}m#^[[0m"if[248,774,1025,1025,1025,774,248][j]&1<<i!=0}}}
d[4,0]
d[0,12]
d[1,24]
d[3,6,3]
d[2,18,3]
$><<a.map{|r|r*''}*$/
```

(Note that `^[` are single characters.)

Sample run:

[image: olympic games logo]

Answer (score 37):

## Mathematica - 185

```
c[x_, y_] := 
 Table[Boole[Abs[(i - x)^2 + (j - y)^2 - 16] < 4], {i, 0, 15}, {j, 0, 
   30}]
MatrixForm@
 Replace[Blue c[5, 4] + Black c[5, 14] + Red c[5, 24] + 
   Yellow c[9, 9] + Green c[9, 19], {0 -> "", 
   c_ + _ | c_ :> Style["*", c]}, {2}]
```

Here is the ouput

[image]

Another version, based on rasterization of vector graphics

```
MatrixForm@
 Replace[ImageData@
   Rasterize[
    Graphics[{Blue, Circle[{4, 9}, 4], Black, Circle[{14, 9}, 4], Red,
       Circle[{24, 9}, 4], Yellow, Circle[{9, 4}, 4], Green, 
      Circle[{19, 4}, 4]}], ImageSize -> {30, 15}], {c_ :> 
    Style["*", RGBColor@c]}, {2}]
```

[image]

Comment: You get points for the prettiest output.

Comment: Nice work.  I posted my own version of your code.

Answer (score 34):

PostScript, 203 (-20 = 183)

```
%!
/Courier findfont 12 scalefont setfont
/l { setrgbcolor translate 20 { 0 30 moveto (*) show 18 rotate } repeat } def
140 200 0 0 1 l 45 -30 1 1 0 l 45 30 0 0 0 l 45 -30 0 1 0 l 45 30 1 0 0 l
showpage
```

I maintain that this counts as "ASCII art", though it doesn't write to the console. Output:

[image: Olympic Rings]

This could be golfed a little more.

Comment: If this is ASCII art, it surely is the first I've seen using rotated asterisks.

Comment: I'm sure it won't be the last.

Answer (score 25):

### Windows Command Script - 112 <strike>percent</strike> bytes

```
%1%0 @echo. set
%2.= oooo 
%2,=o    o
%1%.%%.%%.%&%1%,%%,%%,%&%1o  %.%%.%  o&%1%.%%.%%.%&%1   %,%%,%&%1   %.%%.%
```

[image: 100% Olympic rings]

**And of course, the obligatory cheat'ish version - 4 bytes**

```
%~n0
```

saved as:

```
@echo. oooo  oooo  oooo&echo.o    oo    oo    o&echo.o   oooo  oooo   o&echo. oooo  oooo  oooo&echo.   o    oo    o&echo.    oooo  oooo.cmd
```

Comment: we need more answers in BAT and CMD :)

Answer (score 21):

## Another attempt in Perl, <s>130</s> 120

Thanks to manatwork for helping with this

```
for(qw(15005 40410 802a0 80a28 41414 15005 808 2a0)){$s=sprintf"%20b",hex;$s=~y/01/ #/;print$s.substr(reverse($s),1).$/}
```

Output:

```
   # # #         # # #         # # #   
 #       #     #       #     #       # 
#         # # #         # # #         #
#       # #   # #     # #   # #       #
 #     # #     # #   # #     # #     # 
   # # #         # # #         # # #   
        #       #     #       #        
          # # #         # # #
```

Comment: You can spare: 4 character by using `for` instead of `foreach`; 2 characters by removing `(`…`)` round `sprintf()`'s arguments; 2 characters by removing `hex`'s parameter; 1 character by using `y///` instead of `tr///`; 1 character by removing the final `;`.

Comment: @manatwork Thanks! I've never even heard of `y///` before. Will go and look it up now.

Answer (score 20):

## Python: <s>157</s> <s>140</s> <s>138</s> <s>133</s> <s>122</s> 107 characters

### 107

(thanks to [manatwork](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/18986/draw-the-olympic-games-logo#comment37393_19003))

```
for o in"jzd360 1zlpwci 3ydgr29 20pzv5u jzd360 149ytc b8n40".split():print bin(int(o,36))[2:].rjust(34,'0')
```

sample output:

```
0001001000000001001000000001001000
0100000010000100000010000100000010
1000000001001000000001001000000001
0100000110000110000110000110000010
0001001000000001001000000001001000
0000000100000010000100000010000000
0000000001001000000001001000000000
```

### 157

```
print'\n'.join(['{0:b}'.format(o).rjust(39,'0') for o in [45099909288,137984246274,275230249985,276241138945,137984246274,45099909288,1078001920,352343040]])
```

### 122

(just started this one, I will try to improve it)

```
h=lambda x:bin(int("15bb511iun9aqulod22j8d4 ho8skh  "[x::8],36))[2:].rjust(20)
for x in range(8):print h(x)+h(x)[::-1][1:]
```

---

#### with better output: 120 characters

```
for o in"jzd360 1zlpwci 3ydgr29 20pzv5u jzd360 149ytc b8n40".split():print bin(int(o,36))[2:].replace('0',' ').rjust(34)
```

sample output:

```
   1  1        1  1        1  1   
 1      1    1      1    1      1 
1        1  1        1  1        1
 1     11    11    11    11     1 
   1  1        1  1        1  1   
       1      1    1      1       
         1  1        1  1
```

Comment: What about base 36? This has 140 characters: `print'\n'.join(['{0:b}'.format(int(o,36)).rjust(39,'0')for o in"kpvbkq0 1re099tu 3ifszg1t 3iwiuayp 1re099tu kpvbkq0 httbls 5trxmo".split()])`. Regarding the “better output” version, there you can spare `rjust()`'s second parameter. (And insert a “t” in this post's heading.)

Comment: I was looking for a better solution, yours look great!

Comment: Nice improvement with `bin()`. But why are you using `str()` around it? `bin()`'s return value is already `str`.

Comment: Shouldn't the 5th line be `010000010100000101000101000001010000010`? The bottom two rings look a bit broken to me.

Comment: @manatwork indeed, didn't think about that!

Comment: @squeamishossifrage thanks, looks better now!

Comment: In the `146` character solution you can avoid the `[` and `]` of the list-comprehension inside `str.join`.

Comment: it's in fact even shorter without the list-comprehension (just edited this solution)

Answer (score 17):

## Perl, <s>177</s> 163

An improved version thanks to Dom Hastings:

```
$s=$"x3;print"  .-~-. "x3 .$/." /$s  \\"x3 .$/."|$s$s "x4 ."
 \\$s ./~\\.$s./~\\.$s /
  '-./'$s'\\-/'$s'\\.-'
"."$s |$s"x3 ."
$s "." \\$s  /"x2 ."
$s"."$s'-.-'"x2;
```

Output:

```
  .-~-.   .-~-.   .-~-. 
 /     \ /     \ /     \
|       |       |       |       
 \    ./~\.   ./~\.    /
  '-./'   '\-/'   '\.-'
    |       |       |   
     \     / \     /
      '-.-'   '-.-'
```

Comment: Hooray for Perl! A couple of extra savings: instead of using `"\n"` as `$r`, you can use `$/` which defaults to `"\n"`, literal newlines might even save you more in a couple of places. You can also save 1 more char using `$s=$"x3` rather than `$s="   "`. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 15):

## C, 257 bytes

```
#include <stdio.h>
d(i,j){int r=35;float x=r,y=0;while(--r>0){char s[8]={29,(((int)y+j)/32)+32,(((int)y+j)%32)+96,(((int)x+i)/32)+32,(((int)x+i)%32)+64,31,'.',0};puts(s);x-=0.2*y;y+=0.2*x;}}main(){d(140,200);d(185,170);d(230,200);d(275,170);d(320,200);}
```

This could have been golfed a bit more.

This has to be run on a Tektronix 4010 (or an emulator such as xterm -t). Output:

[image: Ooutput]

This is indeed ASCII art, since those are all '.' characters. And it does output to the console, as requested. Some Tektronix emulators support colour. Mine didn't, so I couldn't do that.

Answer (score 12):

## Haskell, 200

```
main=mapM(putStrLn.map(\b->if b then '#' else ' '))$(map.map)(\(x,y)->or$map(\(n,m)->(<2).abs.(18-)$sqrt$(n-x)^2+(m-y*2)^2)$[(20,20),(60,20),(100,20),(40,40),(80,40)])$map(zip[0..120].repeat)[0..30]
```

Output:

```
            #################                       #################                       #################            
         ########### ###########                 ########### ###########                 ########### ###########         
      #######               #######           #######               #######           #######               #######      
     #####                     #####         #####                     #####         #####                     #####     
   #####                         #####     #####                         #####     #####                         #####   
  #####                           #####   #####                           #####   #####                           #####  
 #####                             ##### #####                             ##### #####                             ##### 
 ####                               #### ####                               #### ####                               #### 
 ####                               #### ####                               #### ####                               #### 
 ###                                 ### ###                                 ### ###                                 ### 
 ####                           #################                       #################                           #### 
 ####                        ########### ###########                 ########### ###########                        #### 
 #####                    #######  ##### #####  #######           #######  ##### #####  #######                    ##### 
  #####                  #####    #####   #####    #####         #####    #####   #####    #####                  #####  
   #####               #####     #####     #####     #####     #####     #####     #####     #####               #####   
     #####            #####    #####         #####    #####   #####    #####         #####    #####            #####     
      #######        #####  #######           #######  ##### #####  #######           #######  #####        #######      
         ########### ###########                 ########### ###########                 ########### ###########         
            #################                       #################                       #################            
                     ###                                 ### ###                                 ###                     
                     ####                               #### ####                               ####                     
                     ####                               #### ####                               ####                     
                     #####                             ##### #####                             #####                     
                      #####                           #####   #####                           #####                      
                       #####                         #####     #####                         #####                       
                         #####                     #####         #####                     #####                         
                          #######               #######           #######               #######                          
                             ########### ###########                 ########### ###########                             
                                #################                       #################
```

golfed out of:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}

olympMids = [(1,1),(3,1),(5,1),(2,2),(4,2)]
circleRadius = 0.9
circleBorder = 0.1
scaleFactor = 20
verticalScale = 0.5

distance :: Floating a => (a,a) -> (a,a) -> a
distance (x,y) (x2,y2) = sqrt $ (x2-x)^2 + (y2-y)^2

match :: (Floating a, Ord a) => (a,a) -> (a,a) -> Bool
match v v2 = (<circleBorder) . abs . (circleRadius-) $ distance v v2

matchOlymp :: (Floating a, Ord a) => (a,a) -> Bool
matchOlymp v = or $ map (match $ scale v) $ olympMids
  where
    scale (x,y) = (x / scaleFactor, y / scaleFactor / verticalScale)

board :: (Enum a, Num a) => a -> a -> [[(a, a)]]
board lx ly = map (zip [0..lx] . repeat) [0..ly]

printOlymp = mapM (putStrLn . map to) $ (map.map) matchOlymp $ board 120 30

main = printOlymp

to :: Bool -> Char
to True = '#'
to False = ' '
```

Comment: i still laugh about the `map.map` because it sounds funny. :D

Comment: It seems kind of bloated ...

Comment: the rings or the code?

Comment: I mean the rings :-)

Answer (score 12):

## Java, <s>181</s> <s>179</s> <s>161</s> 156 bytes

```
enum M{M;{System.out.print(new java.math.BigInteger("2b13bp4vx9rreb1742o0tvtpxntx0mgsfw48c4cf",36).toString(2).replaceAll(".{29}","$0\n"));System.exit(1);}}
```

(Won't compile on jdk 1.7, requires 1.6 or lower)

The output:

```
11100011111110001111111000111
10111110111011111011101111101
01111111000111111100011111110
10111100111001110011100111101
11100011111110001111111000111
11111101111101110111110111111
11111111000111111100011111111
```

Definitely not a winner, but come on, it's *java*.

Comment: Spare 2 characters by not capturing in `replaceAll()`'s regular expression and putting back the entire matched part: `replaceAll(".{29}","$0\n")`. (There may be an extra line break at the end of your file, as I count only 181 characters in the posted code.)

Comment: One more thing: remove the `import` and put the package name directly in the constructor call. That reduces the size to 161 characters.

Comment: Spared another 5 bytes by changing `class M{static{...` to `enum M{M;{...`. Next big step is getting rid of BigInteger, is that possible? I'm trying to do some magic with String.format but have no results yet.

Answer (score 11):

### Ruby, 9

```
p"\044"*5
```

**#satire**

The rules allow for art that does not look exactly like the example, but it must *"represent the Olympic rings well enough that it's recognizable"*.

You may recognize this representation of the Olympic Games logo.

Comment: Funny :) As a Chicagoan, I can tell you that's exactly what the mayor saw when he was courting the games !

Comment: As a Vancouverite (2010 Games), I can also relate. :-)

Comment: I feel like I'm missing out on an inside joke here :-P

Comment: @DoorknobofSnow Try this much more verbose Javascript version in your console: `o=['\044']; o2=o.concat(o); "\t" + o2.concat(o).join(" ") + "\n\t " + o2.join(" ");`

Comment: @AmeliaBR That does basically the same thing... how does that help explain anything?

Comment: @DoorknobofSnow Sorry, I though you were getting confused about character codes.  If you don't get the connection between Olympics and dollar signs, I can't help you there.

Comment: output is: $$$$$

Comment: Just tried in on http://repl.it/languages/Ruby ... got the output: "$$$$$" => nil

Answer (score 11):

## Javascript - 170 <s>185</s> <s>189</s> Chars

```
'jzd36071zlpwci73ydgr29720pzv5u7jzd3607149ytc7b8n40'.split(7).map(function(x){a=parseInt(x,36).toString(2);console.log((Array(35-a.length).join(0)+a).replace(/0/g,' '))})
```

**Output:**

```
   1  1        1  1        1  1    
 1      1    1      1    1      1  
1        1  1        1  1        1 
 1     11    11    11    11     1  
   1  1        1  1        1  1    
       1      1    1      1        
         1  1        1  1
```

## 2nd Javascript - 25 Chars

```
console.log('O O O\n O O')
```

**Output:**

```
O O O 
 O O
```

The second is lazy

Comment: You can spare; 2 characters by using “4” as separator instead of “.” and using digit 4 (without quotes) as `split()`'s parameter; 2 characters by removing the last 2 `;`s.

Comment: A (currently) Firefox-only version of the above can be reduced even more, to 172 characters: `'kpvbkq041re099tu43ifszg1t43iwiuayp41sdk52824kpvbkq04httbls45trxmo'.split(4).map(x=>{a=parseInt(x,36).toString(2);console.log(' '.repeat(39-a.length)+a.replace(/0/g,' '))})`.

Comment: Thanks, added your suggestion, I will leave it browser independent for now.

Comment: ◯ is not ascii...

Comment: @njzk2 Yup, solved it סּ_סּ

Comment: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/19134/2972 :-D

Comment: @Blazemonger Beats me :)

Answer (score 11):

**Binary! (265 CHARS)**

```
0001111100000000111110000000011111000
0100000001000010000000100001000000010
1000000001111100000000011111000000001
0100000011000011000001100001100000010
0001111100000000111110000000011111000
0000000010000001000001000000100000000
0000000001111100000000011111000000000
```

It is too large to win, but at least it looks cool!

Comment: Olympic logo in the Matrix.

Comment: @user13107 What?

Answer (score 10):

## PHP - 99 (-20?)

```
 bbbb  ####  rrrr
b    b#    #r    r
b   ybyy  g#gg   r
 bbyb  ##g#  rrrr
   y    yg    g
    yyyy  gggg
```

That is definitely recognizable. I say that my "colors" count; it's a close representation.

If you don't like that, then here is

## GolfScript - 101 (-20?)

```
' bbbb  ####  rrrr
b    b#    #r    r
b   ybyy  g#gg   r
 bbyb  ##g#  rrrr
   y    yg    g
    yyyy  gggg'
```

Comment: Where's the code?

Comment: @Undo That *is* the code ;-)

Comment: In truth, I don't know PHP. That is the only PHP program/style I know how to write. (Sure I've gone through a tutorial, but I forgot it).

Comment: Wouldn't the PHP one come out as bbbb  ####  rrrr
b    b#    #r    r
b   ybyy  g#gg   r
 bbyb  ##g#  rrrr
   y    yg    g
    yyyy  gggg on the screen?

Comment: @MrLister Nope: http://ideone.com/q2P0lX

Comment: @MrLister Okay, try adding a carriage return at the ends of the lines.

Comment: You need to add `header("Content-Type: text/plain")`, the default for web servers is text/html

Comment: -1 for using the code as the string literal

Answer (score 10):

## Bash + ImageMagick: 163 characters

```bash
e=ellipse
c=,10,5,0,360
convert -size 70x20 xc:black +antialias -stroke white -fill none -draw "$e 10,5$c$e 34,5$c$e 58,5$c$e 22,10$c$e 46,10$c" xpm:-|tr -dc ' .
'
```

Sample output:

```
.

     ...........             ...........             ...........
   ....       ....         ....       ....         ....       ....
 ...             ...     ...             ...     ...             ...
..                 ..   ..                 ..   ..                 ..
..                 ..   ..                 ..   ..                 ..
.                ...........             ...........                .
..             ......   ......         ......   ......             ..
..           ...   ..   ..   ...     ...   ..   ..   ...           ..
 ...        ..   ...     ...   ..   ..   ...     ...   ..        ...
   ....     ......         ......   ......         ......     ....
     ...........             ...........             ...........
            ..                 ..   ..                 ..
            ..                 ..   ..                 ..
             ...             ...     ...             ...
               ....       ....         ....       ....
                 ...........             ...........
```

Answer (score 10):

### Perl 6:  <s>112</s> <s>77</s> 56 characters, 75 bytes

```
say flip .ord.base(2).trans("01"=>" @")for"䔐㣠".comb
```

- Unicde strings! (above string is "\x1C71C\x228A2\x438E1\x26DB2\x1C71C\x4510\x38E0")
- `.comb` gives a List of the separate characters in a String (without argument anyway)
- `.ord` gives character code number from character
- `.base(2)` returns a string with base-2 encoding of that Int
- `.trans` replaces the digits with space and @ for better visibility
- `flip` reverses the characters of a string so that missing leading 0's don't mess up the drawing.

```
  @@@   @@@   @@@
 @   @ @   @ @   @
@    @@@   @@@    @
 @  @@ @@ @@ @@  @
  @@@   @@@   @@@
    @   @ @   @
     @@@   @@@
```

---

edit2: newer solution using qwote words and base-36 encoded

```
say flip :36($_).base(2).trans("01"=>" @")for<2HWC 315U 5XI9 3ESY 2HWC DN4 B8G>
```

- `<ABC DEF GHI>` is a quote-words syntax in perl6, so you get a list of Strings
- `:36($_)` creates an Int from a base-36 encoded string in `$_` (`for` loop default variable)

---

edit: old solution has nicer (copied) drawing but is longer:

```
  say flip :36($_).base(2).trans("01"=>" o")for<KPVBKQ0 1RE099TU 3IFSZG1T 3IWIUAYP 1SDK5282 KPVBKQ0 HTTBLS 5TRXMO>
```

```
   o o o         o o o         o o o
 o       o     o       o     o       o
o         o o o         o o o         o
o       o o   o o     o o   o o       o
 o     o o     o o   o o     o o     o
   o o o         o o o         o o o
        o       o     o       o
          o o o         o o o
```

Answer (score 10):

## Mathematica <s>185</s> 175

10 bytes saved by mathe.

The rings below are ASCII 'O's.

The letter "O", slightly translucent, in Century Gothic, printed 5 times at font size=145 printer points.

This is not terminal art. However it fully satisfies Wikipedia's definition of Ascii art: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII_art.

```
Graphics[{Opacity@.8,Style["O",#]~Text~#2&@@@{{Blue,{-1.5,1}},{Black,{0,1}},{Red,{1.5,1}},{Orange,{-.8,.4}},{Darker@Green,{.8,.4}}}},BaseStyle->{145,FontFamily->"Century Gothic"}]
```

[image: olympic rings]

Comment: As this is not console output, you are better of at the free-style olympics contest: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/19050/15168

Comment: `FontSize -> ` can be removed.

Comment: @mathe, True. I used the font size merely to make the output a reasonable size.

Comment: @DavidC I mean you could replace `FontSize -> 145` by `145`.

Comment: @mathe.  Yes!  Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

**JavaScript: 153 chars**

I wanted to see if I could do it any faster using algebra to actually graph the circles:

```
s="";c=[3,7,11,7,19,7,7,4,15,4];for(y=10;y>0;y--){s+="\n";for(x=0;x<23;x+=.5){t=1;for(i=0;i<9;i+=2){a=x-c[i];b=y-c[i+1];d=a*a+b*b-9;t&=(d<0?-d:d)>3}s+=t}}
```

(`c` is an array of five (x,y) pairs, the centers of the circles, flattened to save ten characters.)

output:

```
1110000000111111111000000011111111100000001111
1000111110001111100011111000111110001111100011
0011111111100111001111111110011100111111111001
0011111111100000001111111110000000111111111001
0011111110000111000011111000011100001111111001
1000111100001111100001110000111110000111100011
1110000000111111111000000011111111100000001111
1111111100111111111001110011111111100111111111
1111111110001111100011111000111110001111111111
1111111111100000001111111110000000111111111111
```

**159 chars** is a little more readable:

```
s="";c=[3,7,11,7,19,7,7,4,15,4];for(y=10;y>0;y--){s+="\n";for(x=0;x<23;x+=.5){t=1;for(i=0;i<9;i+=2){a=x-c[i];b=y-c[i+1];d=a*a+b*b-9;t&=(d<0?-d:d)>3}s+=t?" ":t}}
```

output:

```
   0000000         0000000         0000000    
 000     000     000     000     000     000  
00         00   00         00   00         00 
00         0000000         0000000         00 
00       0000   0000     0000   0000       00 
 000    0000     0000   0000     0000    000  
   0000000         0000000         0000000    
        00         00   00         00         
         000     000     000     000          
           0000000         0000000
```

In **167 chars** we have "colors":

```
s="";c=[3,7,11,7,19,7,7,4,15,4];for(y=10;y>0;y--){s+="\n";for(x=0;x<23;x+=.5){t=1;for(i=0;i<9;i+=2){a=x-c[i];b=y-c[i+1];d=a*a+b*b-9;t&=(d<0?-d:d)>3;h=t?i:h}s+=t?" ":h}}
```

output:

```
   8888888         0000000         2222222    
 888     888     000     000     222     222  
88         88   00         00   22         22 
88         8844400         0066622         22 
88       4444   0044     6600   2266       22 
 888    4444     0004   6000     2226    222  
   8888888         0000000         2222222    
        44         44   66         66         
         444     444     666     666          
           4444444         6666666
```

And with **189 chars**, I can make the radius `r` adjustable as well:

```
r=5;s="";c=[r,0,2*r+1,r,3*r+2,0,4*r+3,r,5*r+4,0];for(y=-r;y<3*r;y++){s+="\n";for(x=0;x<9*r;x+=.5){t=1;for(i=0;i<9;i+=2){a=x-c[i];b=y-c[i+1];d=a*a+b*b-r*r;t&=(d<0?-d:d)>r;h=t?i:h}s+=t?" ":h}}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/5Q6BX/

Answer (score 7):

## APL, 8 chars/bytes*

Here's an answer pushing for lowest char count (this is code golf after all)

```
2 5⍴'○ '
```

Output:

```
○ ○ ○
 ○ ○
```

The symbol is ○, APL circle operator. You can put an 'O' instead, in case you want strictly ASCII output. I just thought it fit to use an APL symbol.

---

Just for kicks, here's a color version (37 chars - 20 = 17 score)

```
2 20⍴'m',⍨¯2↓3↓∈(⊂'m○ ^[[3'),⍪'40132 '
                      ‾‾ ← single Esc character, type Ctrl+V Esc on the terminal
```

Output:
[image: color rings terminal output]
⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯
<sup>*: APL can be written in its own (legacy) single-byte charset that maps APL symbols to the upper 128 byte values. Therefore, for the purpose of scoring, a program of N chars *that only uses ASCII characters and APL symbols* can be considered to be N bytes long.</sup>

Answer (score 7):

## CSS, <del>1176</del> <del>922</del> <del>855</del> 771 bytes, -20 colour bonus = 751

```css
html,head,title,body{display:block; color:transparent; font:bold 1em/1 monospace; height:0}
link,meta,style{display:none}
:before,:after{float:left; color:#000; white-space:pre;
content:'   @@@@@@@\A  @@@     @@@\A@@         @@ \A            @@\A@@         @@\A@@         @@\A  @@@     @@@\A    @@@@  @'}
html:before{color:blue}
title:before,title:after{color:blue; position:absolute; left:0; top:3em; content:'@@'}
title:after{color:red; top:7em; content:'                                   @@'}
head:after{color:red}
body:before{clear:left; content:'     '}
body:after,html:after{position:relative; top:-5em; color:#EC0;
content:'    @  @@@@\A   @@@     @@@\A  @@         @@\A  @@         @@\A  @@\A  @@         @@\A   @@@     @@@\A     @@@@@@@'}
html:after{color:#090}
```

CSS only, no markup needed. See markupless fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/XcBMV/12/

[image: Rings]

In colour, and with the correct overlap.

Answer (score 6):

**Perl - 12 characters**

```
say"OOO\nOO"
```

OK, so it's not an especially artistic rendering. ;-)

Slightly cuter:

```
perl -MTerm::ANSIColor=:constants -E'say ON_BRIGHT_WHITE,BLUE,O,BLACK,O,RED,O,$/,YELLOW,O,GREEN,O,RESET'
```

Answer (score 6):

## GAS Assembly 16-bit BIOS OL loader – 617 - 20 = 597

Going crazy on length here, so mere for the fun of it.

---

It does not load much, but it loads The Olympic Games logo as ASCII with colors ;)

Code:

```
.code16;S:jmp o;nop;o:mov $1984,%ax;mov %ax,%ds;mov %ax,%es;movw $t,%si;r:lodsb;or %al,%al;jz q;cmp $33,%al;jg k;movb $0,c;call X;inc %dh;mov $0,%dl;call G;jmp r;k:sub $48,%al;mov %al,%cl;add %al,c;lodsb;cmp $32,%al;je v;mov %al,%bl;and $15,%bl;mov $35,%al;v:mov $9,%ah;mov $0,%bh;mov $0,%ch;int $16;call X;mov c,%dl;call G;jmp r;q:ret;G:mov $2,%ah;int $16;X:mov $3,%ah;mov $0,%bh;int $16;ret;c:.byte 0;t:.asciz "3 5A9 5H9 5D!1 1A7 1A5 1H7 1H5 1D7 1D!1A9 1A4N9 1H4B9 1D!1A7 1N1 1A3 1H1 1N5 1B1 1H3 1D1 1B7 1D!1 1A5 1N1 1A5 1H1 1N3 1B1 1H5 1D1 1B5 1D!3 4A1N9 4H1B9 5D!8 1N7 1N5 1B7 1B!9 1 5N9 5B!";.=S+510;.word 0xaa55
```

#### (Linux) Build and extract MBR image

```
as -o olymp.o olymp.S
objcopy -O binary olymp.o olymp.img
```

#### Running in emulator

*(Have not tested it on my home computer yet ...)*

```
qemu-system-i386 olymp.img
```

#### Result

[image]

Comment: You sure take the idea of not using external resources to an extreme, don't you? +1

Comment: @AdamMaras: Yes, and there's that ;), had to try. Next is to incorporate a real load of OS. O`Loader II.

Comment: How does it score if you measure the binary, assuming that the disk already had a boot sector so you can skip the 55h AAh at the end (along with any associated padding)?

Comment: @SamB: That would be 275 bytes, 255 pt where the code part is about 91 bytes and the variable + plot data 184 bytes.

Answer (score 5):

## TI-Basic (16 bytes)

Note: TI-Basic is tokenized. If I remember correctly, `ClrHome` and `Disp` are one-byte tokens.

```
ClrHome
Disp "O O O"," O O
```

Answer (score 4):

### Python (318-20)

```
def f(s,i,j,c): 
    for (k,l) in zip([i,i,i+1,i+1,i+2,i+2,i+3,i+3,i+4,i+4,i+5,i+5],[j+2,i+3,j+1,j+4,j,j+5,j,j+5,j+1,j+4,j+2,j+3]):s[k][l]=c+'+'+'\033[0m'
a=[]; 
for i in range(9):a+=[14*[' ']]
for i in [0,4,8]:f(a,0,i,'\033[9%im'%((4*i+4)%5))
for i in [2,6]:f(a,3,i, '\033[9%im'%((i+1)%5))
for l in a:print''.join(l)
```

`a` is a matrix of strings, the function `f` modifies it by drawing a circle at location `i,j` with color `c` using ansi color codes. Finally `a` is printed.

Answer (score 4):

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#define tc textcolor

void circle(int x,int y,int k)
{
  tc(k);
  int n;
  for(n=0;n<=6;n++)
  {

    if(n==0||n==6)
    {
      gotoxy(x+3,y+n);
      cprintf("* * *");
    }
    else if(n==1||n==5)
    {
      gotoxy(x+1,y+n);
      cprintf("*");
      gotoxy(x+9,y+n);
      cprintf("*");
    }
    else if(n>1&&n<5)
    {
      gotoxy(x,y+n);
      cprintf("*");
      gotoxy(x+10,y+n);
      cprintf("*");
    }
  }
}

void main()
{
  clrscr();
  circle(1,1,BLUE);
  circle(14,1,WHITE);
  circle(27,1,RED);
  circle(8,4,YELLOW);
  circle(21,4,GREEN);
  _setcursortype(0);
  getch();
}
```

[image: Made in turbo c++ 3.0 compiler. Tried t make the code as short as possible]

Comment: 1) Please use Markdown to mark [code block](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code) and keep the posted code readable. 2) As this is a [tag:code-golf] challenge, please try to reduce the size of your code to the strictly necessary. 3) Please add a heading line to your answer (emphasized with some markup up to your preference (usually [header 1](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/editing-help#headers) or [bold](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/editing-help#italics-bold))), specifying the used language, the length of the code and the earned score.

Answer (score 4):

## Python - 163 characters (thanks to manatwork!)

```
print("""  000     000     000
 0   0   0   0   0   0
0     000     000     0
 0   0   0   0   0   0
  000     000     000
     0   0   0   0
      000     000""")
```

#### Output:

```
  000     000     000  
 0   0   0   0   0   0 
0     000     000     0
 0   0   0   0   0   0 
  000     000     000  
     0   0   0   0     
      000     000
```

Very simple...

Comment: 1) Count it manually. 2) Use a text editor which displays text size or absolute character position. (Midnight Commander's built-in editor displays absolute positions too: move the cursor at the end of text and the absolute position will be equal with the size.) 3) Save it in a file and look at its size. Or if is already posted, [Code Golf UserScript Enhancement Pack](http://stackapps.com/questions/2048/code-golf-userscript-enhancement-pack) tells it.

Comment: I just used `len()`

Comment: `len()` said it was 170 characters...

Comment: MCEdit says 176. No idea what I miscalculated earlier.

Comment: Minecraft Editor...?

Comment: Midnight Commander's editor.

Comment: that makes much more sense...

Comment: Regarding your code, you can spare: 2 characters by changing for `"…"` to `"""…"""` and using literal newlines instead of `\n`; 11 characters by removing trailing spaces from each line's end. http://pastebin.com/9wQmB2N1 (See RAW Paste Data – their syntax highlight seems to alter the code.)

Comment: Thinking again, that code is composed mostly by repeating two substrings. So you can use those two “Lego® bricks” to build up the logo: http://pastebin.com/9VfqULji

Answer (score 4):

## Coffeescript 123

Input:

```
for t in[y=124830,137313,146673,y,17160,15600]
 n=t.toString 2;k=31-n.length;n=0+n while k--;console.log n.replace /0/g,' '
```

Output:

```
   1111  1111  1111
  1    11    11    1
  1   1111  1111   1
   1111  1111  1111
     1    11    1
      1111  1111
```

Screenshot:

[image: Coffeescript Ascii Olympic Rings]

#### Javascript 136

Input:

```
r=[y=124830,137313,146673,y,17160,15600]
for(i in r){
n=r[i].toString(2)
k=31-n.length
while(k--)n=0+n
console.log(n.replace(/0/g,' '))}
```

Answer (score 3):

**R - 70**

Using CRAN-R statistics. Unfortunately the output goes to X and not to the console. I resubmitted this answer to the [Olympic Games Logo - Free Style Edition](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/19050/15168)

Anyhow, here is the code:

```
l=c(1,9);plot(3:7,c(6,4,6,4,6),col=c(4,7,1,3,2),cex=10,ylim=l,xlim=l)
```

[image: R plot]

Comment: "The program must write the art to the console."

Comment: The challenge calls for ASCII art...

Comment: Indeed, this program does not write art to the console and is therefor obsolete for this contest.

Answer (score 3):

## C - 230 bytes

Not a winner, but draws in a non-intuitive way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define D(p,q) ((int)hypot(x-(p),y-(q))==8)
int main(){int y,x;for(y=0;y<29;y++){for(x=0;x<61;x++)putchar((D(10,10)||D(30,10)||D(50,10)||D(20,18)||D(40,18))?'*':' ');putchar('\n');}return 0;}
```

To compile, `gcc -o ologo ologo.c -lm`.

Output:

```
    *********           *********           *********
   **       **         **       **         **       **
  *           *       *           *       *           *
 *             *     *             *     *             *
**             **   **             **   **             **
*               *   *               *   *               *
*               *   *               *   *               *
*               *   *               *   *               *
*             *********           *********             *
*            ** *   * **         ** *   * **            *
*           *   *   *   *       *   *   *   *           *
*          *    *   *    *     *    *   *    *          *
**        **   **   **   **   **   **   **   **        **
 *        *    *     *    *   *    *     *    *        *
  *       *   *       *   *   *   *       *   *       *
   **     * **         ** *   * **         ** *     **
    *********           *********           *********
          *               *   *               *
          *               *   *               *
          *               *   *               *
          **             **   **             **
           *             *     *             *
            *           *       *           *
             **       **         **       **
              *********           *********
```

Answer (score 2):

**using PASCAL / DELPHI**

```
program Project_olympic_rings;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$R *.res}
uses
  System.SysUtils;
begin
    writeln(' O O O ' + #10 + '  O O ');
    readln;
end.
```

[image: screen dump]

Comment: You can shorten that by removing lines 3, 4, 5, and 8 since they contribute nothing. You can also remove the string concatenation since string and char literals can be written adjacently. There's also a shorter way to write line breaks. In total: `program O;{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}begin writeln('O O O'^M' O O')end.` [62 characters](http://ideone.com/APVv85)

Comment: Or in plain Pascal, 34 characters: `begin write('O O O'#10' O O') end.`

Answer (score 2):

## PowerShell, 555 bytes

Certainly not the shortest, but it's PowerShell with real circle functions and some color!

[image: oic sample image]

```
cls
c 8 8 1
c 16 8 2
c 24 8 3
c 12 15 4
c 20 15 5
w 30 30 . 6
function global:c ([int]$x,[int]$y,[int]$n) {
foreach ($i in 1..360) 
{
$t = [math]::pi * ($i / 180)
w ($x + 5 * [math]::cos($t)) ($y + 5 * [math]::sin($t)) * $n
}
}
function global:w ([int]$x,[int]$y,[string]$c,[int]$n) { 
$p=$host.ui.rawui.cursorposition 
$p.x=$x 
$p.y=$y 
$host.ui.rawui.cursorposition=$p 
$h="green"
switch ($n){ 1 {$h = "blue" } 2 {$h = "black" } 3 {$h = "red" } 4 {$h = "yellow" } 5 {$h = "green" }}
write-host $c -f $h -nonewline
}
```

Comment: Nitpick: the rings aren't supposed to be linked to their neighbors to the left and right.

Comment: Great point, really shows how much I'm into sports. Is it bad etiquette to edit my answer?

Comment: Don't see why it would be.

Answer (score 2):

LAZARUS / FREE PASCAL (with color support , unit CRT)

```
program P;
uses crt;
procedure R(c : Byte);
begin
  TextColor(c);
  write('O ');
end;
begin
  R(blue);
  R(white);
  R(red);
  writeln;
  write(' ');
  r(yellow);
  r(green);
end.
```

[image: screen dump LAZARUS Project]

Comment: As this is a [tag:code-golf] challenge better reduce those 179 characters. For example to 115: http://pastebin.com/kuQM4TiN And please mention your code's length and score too in your answers header line.

Answer (score 2):

## HTML+CSS (222 ch)

First go at code golf so it's not golfed nearly enough but I hadn't spotted anyone using HTML+CSS yet so meh..

```
<style>a{margin:-8px;font-size:4em}a:first-child{color:blue}a:nth-child(3){color:red}a:nth-child(4){color:#ff0}a:last-child{color:#060}a:nth-child(n+4){position:relative;top:-.8em;left:.2em}</style><a>O<a>O<a>O<br><a>O<a>O
```

Someone can probably golf it more. (size for example was just to make it look better!)

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mikecmpbll/LtYCh/1/

Answer (score 2):

### Jquery 503 chars

good challenge!

since I'm a web developer, I used the tools that I use each day... html/jquery/js

check out my answer at jsfiddle.net

http://jsfiddle.net/rYcVV/5/

screenshot of rings attached...
[image]

code minified
    `<div id="rings"/><div id="rings"/>var color=["#06f","#000","red","#fa0","#193"],lefty=[150,300,450,225,380],toppy=[50,50,50,100,100];for(var j=0;j<color.length;j++){for(var i=0;i<36;i++){$("#rings").append('<span class="x'+j+'" style="color:'+color[j]+";;display:inline-block;position:absolute;left:"+lefty[j]+"px;top:"+toppy[j]+'px;height:150px;transform-origin: bottom bottom;width:15px;">*</span>')}}for(var m=0;m<color.length;m++){for(var k=0;k<36;k++){$($("span.x"+m)[k]).css("transform","rotate("+(10*k)+"deg)")}};`

Comment: 1) Your jsFiddle has wrong setup. For Framework you picked “No Library (pure JS)” so the jQuery code not works. 2) jsFiddle or similar link is welcome, but optional. You have to post your code here. 3) Please add a heading line to your post and specify the used language there. (Maybe the required jQuery version too – the output I managed to get from your code is always uglier than your screenshot.) 4) As this is a [tag:code-golf] challenge, reduce your code to the bare minimum and include the code size in your post's heading.

Comment: corrected missing jquery library thanks.

Comment: Maybe you should mention that requires Chrome. The output is equally ugly in Explorer, Firefox and Opera.

Comment: wow, you're a bit of a hater aren't you? I just looked at that link with internet explorer 9 and it looked the same as in chrome. http://jsfiddle.net/rYcVV/1/ , firefox does not look very good tho.

Comment: Sorry if you felt any hate in my comment, but I really believe _this_ is ugly: http://i.stack.imgur.com/WoVO9.png Taken in Explorer 11.

Comment: added hack for firefox http://jsfiddle.net/rYcVV/3/

Comment: Looks much better now.

Comment: made another change, I think it will work in IE11, but I don't have that browser right now. http://jsfiddle.net/rYcVV/5/

Comment: Yes, this version works fine in Explorer 11, while still displays correctly in Chrome, Firefox and Opera.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 90 bytes

This matches the sample output exactly.

[image: Code in text editor]
[image: Console output]

The code is displayed in a screenshot as it contains control characters that I can't post on Stack Exchange. Here is a longer, equivalent version using character codes that I can post here:

```
<?echo gzinflate("SP\0\1-0D\58Åx¹\x14P\$´Ðhœb¼\\˜æ)(\x10%†M+‘NFÕª…†q‰Aµb*\"d\x08\\#Yáª€%Üð\4Š‚\2v-8‚_X§\0");
```

That is 109 bytes but the version in the screenshot using control characters is 90 bytes.

Comment: Instead of making a screenshot of your editor, paste in the code!

Comment: I took a screenshot because it contains control characters that wouldn't be visible here.

Comment: ... Isn't it cheating to write the program in binary?

Comment: @SamB - It is well within the rules currently listed.

Answer (score 1):

### *Mathematica*, 132

Further golfing of swish's fine method:

```
x_~f~y_:=Boole[E<Norm@{#-x,#2-y}<4.3]&~Array~{13,30}

Grid@Replace[Hue/@{E,{0,0,0},0,π,.3}.f@@@{5|5,5|15,5|25,9|10,9|20},0->"",c_+_.:>Style["*",c]},{2}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## Bash / base64 / zcat, 125

```
$ base64 -d<<<H4sIAKc54FIAA1NQUFDQAkMEwMrnUoCLEaS5UHUrKODlcxG0G4dqLahZWjj4Ckiuxq0KxgKpJT4sUH2M3V+oclhpJDW47AIAX9PRBqIBAAA=|zcat
    * * *           * * *           * * *
  *       *       *       *       *       *
*           *   *           *   *           *
*           * * *           * * *           *
*         * *   * *       * *   * *         *
  *     * *       * *   * *       * *     *
    * * *           * * *           * * *
        *           *   *           *
          *       *       *       *
            * * *           * * *
$
```

Answer (score 1):

## TeX, 169

```
\color{blue}\put(0,2){\circle{5}}\color{black}\put(6,2){\circle{5}}\color{red}\put(12,2){\circle{5}}\color{yellow}\put(2,0){\circle{5}}\color{green}\put(9,0){\circle{5}}
```

[image]

Converting the resulting image to ASCII characters:

## Java

```
public class Converter {     
    public static String convertImage(BufferedImage img)  {
        BufferedImage image = img;
 
        char[] tones = new char[]{'*', '*', '*', '*', '*',  ' '};
        int tone = 0;
        
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
 
        Color color; 
 
        for (double y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++) {
            for (double x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++) {
                color = new Color(image.getRGB((int) x, (int) y));
                
                tone = (color.getRed() + color.getGreen() + color.getBlue()) / 3;
                tone = tone / (256 / tones.length - 1);
 
                while (tone > tones.length - 1) tone--;
                
                stringBuilder.append(tones[tone] + " ");
            }
            stringBuilder.append("\n");
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
    
    public static void main(String args[ ]) { 
        BufferedImage image = null;
        Writer writer;
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\OlympicRings.gif"));
            
            writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("C:\\ascii-conversion.txt")));
            writer.append((convertImage(image)));
            writer.close();
            
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }    
}
```

it gives -

```
          * * * * * *                             * * * * * *                             * * * * * *           
      * *             * *                     * *             * *                     * *             * *       
    *                     *                 *                     *                 *                     *     
  *                         *             *                         *             *                         *   
  *                         *             *                         *             *                         *   
*                             *         *                             *         *                             * 
*                             *         *                             *         *                             * 
*                             * * * * * * *                           * * * * * * *                           * 
*                           * *         *   * *                     * *         *   * *                       * 
*                         *   *         *       *                 *   *         *       *                     * 
*                       *     *         *         *             *     *         *         *                   * 
  *                     *   *             *       *             *   *             *       *                 *   
  *                   *     *             *         *         *     *             *         *               *   
    *                 *   *                 *       *         *   *                 *       *             *     
      * *             * *                     * *   *         * *                     * *   *         * *       
          * * * * * * *                           * * * * * * *                           * * * * * *           
                      *                             *         *                             *                   
                      *                             *         *                             *                   
                        *                         *             *                         *                     
                        *                         *             *                         *                     
                          *                     *                 *                     *                       
                            * *             * *                     * *             * *                         
                                * * * * * *                             * * * * * *
```

Answer (score 1):

## Math

```
|f(x)|=sqrt(1-x^2)
f(x+2)
f(x-2)
f(x+1)-1
f(x-1)-1
```

For the output to be able to be graphed with a computer I had to add:

```
g(x)=-f(x)
g(x+2)
g(x-2)
g(x+1)-1
g(x-1)-1
```

And remove the |'s from the first line.

But they don't *really* have to be there.

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1):

## C# [202]

Basic foreach loop in C#

```
class P{static void Main(){foreach(var i in new[]{0x3c7f1fc7,0x37ddf77d,0x2fe3f8fe,0x379ce73d,0x3c7f1fc7,0x3fbeefbf,0x3fe3f8ff})System.Console.WriteLine(System.Convert.ToString(i,2).Replace('1',' '));}}
```

Result Below

```
    000       000       000
  0     0   0     0   0     0
 0       000       000       0
  0    00   00   00   00    0
    000       000       000
       0     0   0     0
         000       000
```

Linq Version 215 Characters

```
namespace System.Linq{class P{static void Main(){new[]{0x3c7f1fc7,0x37ddf77d,0x2fe3f8fe,0x379ce73d,0x3c7f1fc7,0x3fbeefbf,0x3fe3f8ff}.ToList().ForEach(i=>Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(i,2).Replace('1',' ')));}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

**PROCESSING** B/W (78 characters)

No output to the console but still fun to participate. Colours add a lot to the code so it is not worth the 20 points in this case.

> float
>   i,s=9,k=1;for(i=1;i<6;i++){k=i;if(i>3){s=13;k=i*1-2.5;}text("O",k*8,s);}

[image]

Colour (150-20=130 characters)

> float
>   r=0,g=0,b=255,i,s=9,k=1;for(i=1;i<6;i++){k=i;if(i>3){s=12;k=k-2.5;g=255;r=(5-i)*255;}if(i==3){r=255;}if(i==2){b=0;}fill(r,g,b);text("O",k*9,s);}

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## gnuplot 42 characters

```
se te du
uns bor
uns tic
p '-' w ell not
1 4
2 3
3 4
4 3
5 4
e
```

Output:

```
             **                       **                      **
       ******  ******           ******  ******          ******  ******
    ***              ***     ***              ***    ***              ***
  ***                  *** ***                  ******                  ***
  *                      * *                      **                      *
  *                      ***                      **                      **
  *                **************           **************                **
  *             ***      * *     ***     ***      **      ***             *
  ***         ***      *** ***     *** ***      ******      ***         ***
    ***       *      ***     ***     * *      ***    ***      *       ***
       **************           **************          **************
             **                      ***                      **
              *                      * *                      *
              ***                  *** ***                  ***
                ***              ***     ***              ***
                   **************           **************
```

## Shorter version (with axes) 27 characters

```
se te du
p '-' w ell
1 4
2 3
3 4
4 3
5 4
e
```

Output:

```
  5.5 ++----------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+---------++
      +           +          +           +          +           '-' ****** +
    5 ++                                                                  ++
      |     ************           ************           ************     |
      |  ***            ***     ***            ***     ***            ***  |
  4.5 +**                  ** **                  ** **                  **+
      **                    ***                    ***                    **
    4 *+                     *                      *                     +*
      *                ************           ************                 *
  3.5 **            ***     ***    ***     ***     ***    ***             **
      |**         **       ** **      ** **       ** **      **          **|
      |  ***     **     ***     ***    ***     ***     ***    **      ***  |
    3 ++    ************           ************           ************    ++
      |          *                      *                      *           |
  2.5 ++         **                    ***                    **          ++
      |           **                  ** **                  **            |
      |             ***            ***     ***            ***              |
    2 ++               ************           ************                ++
      +           +          +           +          +           +          +
  1.5 ++----------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+---------++
      0           1          2           3          4           5          6
```

Answer (score 0):

## HTML + CSS ( 209 characters )

This isn't really much better than the other HTML / CSS attempt, but I wanted to try this for myself!  removing font size will again shrink down a teeny bit.

```
<style>e:after{content:'o';font-size:2em}e{position:absolute;color:#00f}e>e{left:9px;color:#000}e e e{color:red}e e e e{left:-4px;top:9px;color:#0F0}e e e e e{left:-9px;top:0;color:#ff0}</style><e><e><e><e><e>
```

fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/rV4eQ/

it's not really kosher code, but the e seemed fun to use.

Answer (score 0):

## PERL, 15 characters

```
say"O O O
 O O"
```

To be invoked with `-E`.

```
O O O
 O O
```

Answer (score 0):

## TI-Basic (15 bytes)

This really ought to be a comment on @bb94 's answer, but I don't have the reputation for that yet.

```
ClrHome
Disp "O O O
" O O
```

I saved a byte by omitting a closing quote and using the fact that programs print the final line without being explicitly told to.  This also avoids the "Done" that would be printed otherwise.