# ASCII PPCG Beta Logo Golf

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, kolmogorov-complexity

We shall soon have a new logo & site design, let us use this last breath of the simple times and golf this ASCII version of the speech bubble beta logo:

````````````````````
+-------------------------------------------+
|    .---------------------------------.    |
|   .EPEpEpBPEpEGCXCgCgCGJgCgP&PWP&P&P&Y`   |
|  .RSRsRWRSRsRsHoNoNONxNONONuJuSUSUSVSUS`  |
|  :o@OTO@O@O@W@IDiDIWiDIDIDWZEZeZEWEZeZE-  |
|  :GWGFGfGFKFGFMEMwMEMEMeXEMZLZLWLZLzLZH-  |
|  :rLRLRLXLRLrLMBMGMGmGXGMGMLzTZLZLZLYLZ-  |
|  :AOAoBOAOAOAYAOAoAoBOAOAoAWZEZEZEVEZEZ-  |
|  :MGVGm!'""'!GRLr!'""'!LRKRS!'""'!uSuSU-  |
|  :XEME' .''% !Gf' .;G% 'GFG' .;P% '&PVP-  |
|  :IDID  !DI! !V! .OPoYOPOP!  -gCGCGHGCG-  |
|  :NONw  ``` .OR! .RWRRRRRR! !ONo* 'ONON-  |
|  :GBGC  !CXCGCP! !POP; !xOP  `IJ; `!IDW-  |
|  :P&P&._!&P&P&F~.____.;GFGF~.____.;eJEM-  |
|  :USUSVSUSuSuTLRlRLRWRLRlRLWMGMGmGwGmGM-  |
|  :ZeWEZEZeZWZeOAOaKAOAOaOwOOAoAOXoAoAOA-  |
|  :wLZLZLzHZLZLGMxMgMGMgBGMGLRLXLRLrLRTr-  |
|  :LZLZLYLZLZLzBMEMEMEyEmEMEfBFGFGfGWGFG-  |
|  :EZEVEZEZeZVZDIdIDYdIdIDIx@O@o@oKO@O@o-  |
|  `SkSuSuSUXUSuONOVONOnONWNOSRSRWRSRSRS-   |
|   `.&P&PVP&P&PCXcGCGCGVGcGCEPYPEpEPE?.-   |
|      ```````````````````:STACKE-`````     |
|                         :XCHA-`           |
|                         :NG-`             |
|           ?=W...HWYWVWB :E`               |
+-------------------------------------------+
````````````````````

This is [kolmogorov-complexity](/questions/tagged/kolmogorov-complexity) [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so it's straight forward, output all the text that appears in the above code-block in as few bytes of code as possible, without any funny-business.

#### input

None

#### Output

The ASCII content of the code-block above as a return value or printed to STDOUT or equivalent;
carriage returns `(13)` and/or new lines `(10)` are acceptable;
a trailing empty line is also allowed.

#### Update

The original aim of this challenge was to have a puzzle aspect. It seems this has not been noticed, so I have decided to make the puzzle portion *significantly* easier, but still present, by performing a couple of steps to get you going:

1. There is a use of the string `"STACKEXCHANGE"` in the very bottom portion of the speech-bubble.
2. If one reads the rows of text in the main-portion of the speech-bubble, one might notice an almost repetitive nature of pairs of letters, for example the fourth row reads `"GWGFGfGFKFGFMEMwMEMEMeXEMZLZLWLZLzLZH"` which is almost `"GFGFGFGFGFGFMEMEMEMEMEMEMZLZLZLZLZLZH"`, except some letters have been changed either to another letter (e.g. the second letter from `F` to `W`), to lower-case (e.g. the sixth letter from `F` to `f`), or both (e.g. the sixteenth letter from `E` to `w`). The rows seem to all conform to such a pattern with a 12-13-12 character split (ignoring the mess of the `PPG` logo's white space and border).
3. The process described in (2), once noticed, should be quite easy to undo for the unmasked rows of the speech-bubble (the top six and bottom seven), by first converting the whole text to upper-case and then replacing the odd-ones-out and results in:

````````````````````
+-------------------------------------------+
|    .---------------------------------.    |
|   .EPEPEPEPEPEGCGCGCGCGCGCGP&P&P&P&P&P`   |
|  .RSRSRSRSRSRSNONONONONONONUSUSUSUSUSUS`  |
|  :O@OTO@O@O@O@IDIDIWIDIDIDIZEZEZEZEZEZE-  |
|  :GFGFGFGFGFGFMEMEMEMEMEMEMZLZLZLZLZLZL-  |
|  :RLRLRLRLRLRLMGMGMGMGMGMGMLZLZLZLZLZLZ-  |
|  :AOAOAOAOAOAOAOAOAOBOAOAOAEZEZEZEZEZEZ-  |
|  :MGVGm!'""'!GRLr!'""'!LRKRS!'""'!uSuSU-  |
|  :XEME' .''% !Gf' .;G% 'GFG' .;P% '&PVP-  |
|  :IDID  !DI! !V! .OPoYOPOP!  -gCGCGHGCG-  |
|  :NONw  ``` .OR! .RWRRRRRR! !ONo* 'ONON-  |
|  :GBGC  !CXCGCP! !POP; !xOP  `IJ; `!IDW-  |
|  :P&P&._!&P&P&F~.____.;GFGF~.____.;eJEM-  |
|  :USUSUSUSUSURLRLRLRLRLRLRLGMGMGMGMGMGM-  |
|  :ZEZEZEZEZEZEOAOAOAOAOAOAOOAOAOAOAOAOA-  |
|  :ZLZLZLZLZLZLGMGMGMGMGMGMGLRLRLRLRLRLR-  |
|  :LZLZLZLZLZLZEMEMEMEMEMEMEFGFGFGFGFGFG-  |
|  :EZEZEZEZEZEZDIDIDIDIDIDID@O@O@O@O@O@O-  |
|  `SUSUSUSUSUSUONONONONONONOSRSRSRSRSRS-   |
|   `.&P&P&P&P&PCGCGCGCGCGCGCEPEPEPEPEP.-   |
|      ```````````````````:STACKE-`````     |
|                         :XCHA-`           |
|                         :NG-`             |
|           ?=W...HWYWVWB :E`               |
+-------------------------------------------+
````````````````````

4. While carrying out (3) one may notice a couple of things. First the least obvious: that the only `?`, in the very bottom-right became a `P`, whereas the extra text at the bottom says `?=W...`, and that a large proportion of replaced characters were also `W`. Second that the odd-ones out in upper-case were `B,H,J,K,T,V,W,X,Y`. Third that the odd-ones out occurred every seven letters. The second and third observation helps to fill in the middle rows - which, if we remove the `PCG` mask of spaces and non-letters, non `&` (used in the top and bottom row) and replace it with the letters yields:

````````````````````
+-------------------------------------------+
|    .---------------------------------.    |
|   .EPEPEPEPEPEGCGCGCGCGCGCGP&P&P&P&P&P`   |
|  .RSRSRSRSRSRSNONONONONONONUSUSUSUSUSUS`  |
|  :O@O@O@O@O@O@IDIDIWIDIDIDIZEZEZEZEZEZE-  |
|  :GFGFGFGFGFGFMEMEMEMEMEMEMZLZLZLZLZLZL-  |
|  :RLRLRLRLRLRLMGMGMGMGMGMGMLZLZLZLZLZLZ-  |
|  :AOAOAOAOAOAOAOAOAOBOAOAOAEZEZEZEZEZEZ-  |
|  :MGMGMGMGMGMGRLRLRLRLRLRLRSUSUSUSUSUSU-  |
|  :MEMEMEMEMEMEGFGFGFGFGFGFG&P&P&P&P&P&P-  |
|  :IDIDIDIDIDIDOPOPOPOPOPOPOCGCGCGCGCGCG-  |
|  :NONONONONONORRRRRRRRRRRRRONONONONONON-  |
|  :GCGCGCGCGCGCPOPOPOPOPOPOPDIDIDIDIDIDI-  |
|  :P&P&P&P&P&P&FGFGFGFGFGFGFEMEMEMEMEMEM-  |
|  :USUSUSUSUSURLRLRLRLRLRLRLGMGMGMGMGMGM-  |
|  :ZEZEZEZEZEZEOAOAOAOAOAOAOOAOAOAOAOAOA-  |
|  :ZLZLZLZLZLZLGMGMGMGMGMGMGLRLRLRLRLRLR-  |
|  :LZLZLZLZLZLZEMEMEMEMEMEMEFGFGFGFGFGFG-  |
|  :EZEZEZEZEZEZDIDIDIDIDIDID@O@O@O@O@O@O-  |
|  `SUSUSUSUSUSUONONONONONONOSRSRSRSRSRS-   |
|   `.&P&P&P&P&PCGCGCGCGCGCGCEPEPEPEPEP.-   |
|      ```````````````````:STACKE-`````     |
|                         :XCHA-`           |
|                         :NG-`             |
|           ?=W...HWYWVWB :E`               |
+-------------------------------------------+
````````````````````

1. Now reading the columns one can see that the "input" text to make this base grid was `PROGRAMMINGPUZZLES&CODEGOLFPROGRAMMINGPUZZLES&CODEGOLF@SE`.

The lower-casing and replacement characters are to be determined by you, but also note that the ten remaining letters in the alphabet after removing those present in that string are `B,H,J,K,Q,T,V,W,X,Y` - the replacements plus `Q`.

Comment: Kind of [related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/64763/53748).

Comment: Just wondering, how did you generate this?

Comment: @Oliver Python and Notepad++. Part of the puzzle is to find any patterns in the data of course (although I cannot say if a pure compression will triumph).

Comment: @Downvoters Can you please explain the downvotes?

Comment: @TùxCräftîñg they probably think it looks too random? Or maybe my art is no good .

Comment: Are trailing spaces allowed?

Comment: I downvoted because ASCII-art challenges should have some pattern or sequence (same with kolmogorov-complexity), but this is an arbitrary image which isn't even a proper ASCII representation of the PPCG logo, nor does it even use a consistent pattern of characters

Comment: @Downgoat there *is* pattern to the majority of the characters. I thought part of the challenge of kolmogorov-complexity was to find those patterns.

Comment: @daHugLenny - At present, no, I have specified one trailing `\n`, `\r` or pair of the two, but if there is a valid reason why it would be necessary in some set of languages I would, of course, consider it; let me know.

Comment: @JonathanAllan At that point this challenge might be better suited for puzzling.

Comment: @ConorO'Brien - I actually said the same myself. But note that the [tag:kolmogorov-complexity] info does say "The output will preferably have non-obvious and unknown patterns. The challenge of Kolmogorov complexity is mainly to find those patterns". Also I think it just might be possible using a golfing language in less than the Bubblegum answer if one finds and exploits those patterns.

Comment: the line at the bottom definitely isn't in the logo.

Comment: @ricyje you are correct.

Comment: "We shall soon have a new logo & site design" Ahahahahahahah. ha. haha. ha

Comment: @Geobits - before anyone finds the hidden pattern it seems.

Answer (score 4):

## [Bubblegum](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Bubblegum), <s>542</s> 541 bytes

Reversible hexdump:

```
00000000: d2d6 251e 68f3 72d5 002a 2903 1637 6138  ..%.h.r..*)..7a8
00000010: 8a7f 9578 7027 0c9a 0fd0 32ae 6a63 b435  ...xp'....2.jc.5
00000020: 2668 6734 00e7 d8d9 32b6 cea3 4769 57c6  &hg4....2...GiW.
00000030: 3efb 5e94 1a60 07c7 e5f1 7f89 f033 35ff  >.^..`.......35.
00000040: a725 18f4 5d92 5aec cf88 53a6 d80b 7b09  .%..].Z...S...{.
00000050: adf3 a88e f610 5fc3 d583 d228 a869 279c  ......_....(.i'.
00000060: 1665 f15a e8c1 5f93 3eef 7399 5f72 099d  .e.Z.._.>.s._r..
00000070: d6a7 f20b 54a1 da1b 3eef 9772 2b97 567a  ....T...>..r+.Vz
00000080: 99ae beaf 528d 82b4 61a6 334c 0f3e 9b70  ....R...a.3L.>.p
00000090: ae79 cc77 3cde c43c 164c 9c05 83ba 9a09  .y.w<..<.L......
000000a0: 9399 4ca3 ae99 491c 7ecc 0aa8 461d 3311  ..L...I.~...F.3.
000000b0: 0a2e f881 d770 915d b7b8 036a 32e3 f040  .....p.]...j2..@
000000c0: 067d 2803 ab06 d58f 5798 b561 5695 7587  .}(.....W..aV.u.
000000d0: 0b5e f183 e7df ddf9 1ec7 2f8c abac d814  .^......../.....
000000e0: e5b8 3c95 38b1 c3f1 94cc 27d4 f7ef 89c7  ..<.8.....'.....
000000f0: 7758 2df8 3df1 711e bb54 583e a84a 39dc  wX-.=.q..TX>.J9.
00000100: 7681 106f 957a c4ab 3c42 a5ea 1ba9 a4f2  v..o.z..<B......
00000110: 0899 2181 8827 2887 a3c3 6742 dab6 0559  ..!..'(...gB...Y
00000120: 0047 06c3 c0dd 32ef 3f11 5f82 7038 0f79  .G....2.?._.p8.y
00000130: 84dd a31a 3b29 30d8 7841 bc8b 54d8 235d  ....;)0.xA..T.#]
00000140: 2f48 eb21 0387 db94 e993 37a4 1dff a54f  /H.!......7....O
00000150: 1878 fc98 4feb 6ecd 84c3 6f39 a303 dbac  .x..O.n...o9....
00000160: f889 1034 0ab3 1e33 38a3 84c3 4da7 d990  ...4...38...M...
00000170: b736 1d1a fe75 1358 9767 697b 2feb de7a  .6...u.X.gi{/..z
00000180: e0f0 f390 dc35 b1ce c545 ecb1 e93e c4c6  .....5...E...>..
00000190: 53d6 c5f6 e8f0 5bce d035 14cc ea37 3bc0  S.....[..5...7;.
000001a0: 7761 3cbc 4d1a eef0 5bce 9da9 cc2a 7d4e  wa<.M...[....*}N
000001b0: 57cd b3f5 f482 77b4 5ff6 1b69 e709 6fcb  W.....w._..i..o.
000001c0: 1fe5 9073 8dd3 a2c5 15ea 97cc 752e 4b7c  ...s........u.K|
000001d0: 031a 0581 1e71 f014 1d44 ced6 a3fa 1b8f  .....q...D......
000001e0: a08a 6366 aab1 5f98 628f d4e1 76b4 ff8f  ..cf.._.b...v...
000001f0: 79b9 0da2 0d9b 0d17 401c fee6 98d7 5112  y.......@.....Q.
00000200: ccda e9fa 3d3c e70e 7e0b 7ffc ac29 a589  ....=<..~....)..
00000210: 6e74 a543 34cc c113 fea1 bfa5 7f         nt.C4........
```

[Try it online!](http://bubblegum.tryitonline.net#code=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-LnMuX3IuLgowMDAwMDA3MDogZDZhNyBmMjBiIDU0YTEgZGExYiAzZWVmIDk3NzIgMmI5NyA1NjdhICAuLi4uVC4uLj4uLnIrLlZ6CjAwMDAwMDgwOiA5OWFlIGJlYWYgNTI4ZCA4MmI0IDYxYTYgMzM0YyAwZjNlIDliNzAgIC4uLi5SLi4uYS4zTC4-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-Lko5LgowMDAwMDEwMDogNzY4MSAxMDZmIDk1N2EgYzRhYiAzYzQyIGE1ZWEgMWJhOSBhNGYyICB2Li5vLnouLjxCLi4uLi4uCjAwMDAwMTEwOiAwODk5IDIxODEgODgyNyAyODg3IGEzYzMgNjc0MiBkYWI2IDA1NTkgIC4uIS4uJyguLi5nQi4uLlkKMDAwMDAxMjA6IDAwNDcgMDZjMyBjMGRkIDMyZWYgM2YxMSA1ZjgyIDcwMzggMGY3OSAgLkcuLi4uMi4_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)

Just Zopfli'd the string for 1 million iterations. Running for 100 million iterations does not yield a shorter solution.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 780 Bytes

```
<?=gzinflate(base64_decode("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"));
```

Maybe helpful maybe not I do not know
I give up to find an other way.
beginning the first line at 1
you could concat lines they have the sum 24 with one letter
starts with the W in the middle go up go left and go reverse the 2 line down then concat the first letter of line 13 with the end of line 11 and go to the middle 
now I assume that you must go down to line 14

It seems for me that "?=W...HWYWVWB" is a hint to solve this

Comment: Thanks for taking the effort to look for patterns! Indeed the extra text at the bottom is part of a pre-golf puzzle. I am in the process of updating the question to give some more insight...

Comment: @JonathanAllan Could it been that my feeling that I can read "I DID IT ON PCG" is right?

Comment: No, I saw that too :D. My upcoming update will get you the "input" text...

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby, 788 bytes

Basically the same method as the PHP solution.

```
puts Zlib.inflate Base64.decode64 "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"
```